# How to save "Hex Data" to a file (ASCII) in CAPL including the "NULL" character (0x00)?

Tags: hex, ascii, capl, null-character

In CAPL code, I have a "byte[]" array, this array is supposed to hold "Hex" values (00..FF).

The problem is that, when I try to save the "Hex" array to a file in "ASCII" format, it completely ignores "00" (which is the "NULL" character) resulting in corrupting the output file.

```
variables
{
    byte UploadedData[56, 41, 4C, 00, 01, 02, 00, 02];
    char ExportedTextFile[9];
    char FileName[32] = "FlasherImage.can";
    dword FileHandle = 0;
}

void ExportDataFile(void)
{  
    int u16Index = 0;


    FileHandle = OpenFileWrite(FileName, 0);  

    for (u16Index = 0; u16Index < 8; u16Index++)
    { 
        snprintf(ExportedTextFile, elcount(ExportedTextFile), "%c", UploadedData[u16Index]);

        filePutString(ExportedTextFile, elcount(ExportedTextFile), FileHandle);
    }

    fileClose(FileHandle);
}
```

The Expected File Shall Be:
VALNULSOHSTXNULSTX

The Obtained File is ("NUL" is ignored):
VALSOHSTXSTX

where:
V: Character 'V'.
A: Character 'A'.
L: Character 'L'.
NUL: "NULL" Control Character.
SOH: "Start Of Header" Control Character.
STX: "Start of Text" Control Character.

Please, help me with any solution or workaround.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer :)

Simply, do not write in "ASCII" mode and do not use "snprintf()" that interprets "Binary Data" as "ASCII Data" (characters).

New Code:

```
void ExportBinaryFile(void)
{    
  FileHandle = OpenFileWrite(FileName, 1); 
  fileWriteBinaryBlock(UploadedData, elcount(UploadedData), FileHandle);
  fileClose(FileHandle);
}
```